# Modify the boxing of algorthim2e to get the title on the line

Tags: algorithm2e

I know the algorithm2e package allows to box an algorithm, but 
what I would like to achieve is something like:

```
+--------    Algorithm blablabla   --------+
|                                          |
|    Input:  blabla                        |
|    Output: blabla                        |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|    1. ... the algorithm                  |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                                          |
|    n. end                                |
|                                          |
|                                          |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Is it possible to change the package to get all the algorithm environments looks like this?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered, commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
    algotitle/.style={title={\strut
        Algorithm~\thetcbcounter\ifstrempty{#1}{\ignorespaces}{:~#1}}}}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{algo}[1][]{%
    colback=white,
    colframe=black,
    boxrule=1pt,
    titlerule=0pt,
    sharp corners,
    colbacktitle=white,enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-10pt},
    boxed title style={boxrule=-1pt},
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=black,
    algotitle={},
    #1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{algo}[algotitle=Blablabla, label=myalgo]
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \Input{bla in}
    \Output{bla out}
    the algorithm

    end
\end{algorithm}
\end{algo}
The caption of Algorithm \ref{myalgo} is above. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user159972 You're welcome, thank you for accepting my answer and please don't forget to add a MWE to your next question it makes it easier to answer!